unsure about my mistake with this related rates problem.
I've seen solutions to this type of question on the site here, and have successfully solved some variants. But for some reason my solution to this particular problem doesn't jibe with what Mr. Sal Khan gets (and I tend to trust him more !).

The video for the problem solution steps is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPOjnyjii-4&t=326s&ab_channel=KhanAcademy -  and the answer Mr. Khan gets is: -160ft/sec.   I get -34ft/sec.
Can anyone spot the error?
Here is the problem:
An owl is diving straight down, at 20 feet per second,
for its dinner - a mouse 10 feet from the base of a 20 foot high street lamp. Find: when the bird is 15  feet above the mouse, how fast is its shadow moving.
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \text w=15  \\
& \text dw/dt = -20  \\
& \text { By similar triangles: } \frac{20}{10+y}=\frac{w}{y} \\
& 20 y=(10+y) \cdot w=10 w+w \cdot y \\
& 20 y-w \cdot y=10 w \\
& y(20-\omega)=10 \omega \\
& y=\frac{10 \omega}{20-\omega}=10 \omega \cdot(20-\omega)^{-1} \\
& \frac{d y}{d t}=\frac{d}{d t}\left[10 w \cdot(20-w)^{-1}\right] \\
& =10\left[\frac{d}{d t}\left(\omega \cdot(20-\omega)^{-1}\right]\right. \\
& =10\left[\frac{d w}{d t} \cdot(20-\omega)^{-1}+\frac{d}{d t}(20-\omega)^{-1} \cdot \omega\right] \\
& \begin{array}{ll}
& =10\left[\frac{-20}{20-15}+(-1)(20-w)^{-2} \frac{d}{d t}(20-w) \cdot w\right]
\end{array} \\
& =10\left[\frac{-20}{5}-\frac{1}{(20-\omega)^2} \cdot \frac{d(-\omega)}{d t} \cdot \omega\right] \\
& =10\left[-4-\frac{1}{(20-15)^2} \cdot(-1) \cdot 15\right] \\
& =10\left[-4+\frac{1}{5^{2}} \cdot 15\right] \\
& =10\left[-4+\frac{15}{25}\right] \\
& =10\left[\frac{-4 \cdot 5}{5}+\frac{3}{5}\right] \\
& =10\left[\frac{-20+3}{5}\right]=2[3-20]=2(-17)=-34 \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$

$\frac{d(-w)}{dt}$ is $-\frac{dw}{dt}$, not simply $-1$.

So is $w = \omega$?

@peterwhy -  You nailed it.    Now i know to look out for that dumb mistake in the future..  Once i corrected that step everything worked out per khan academy expectations ;^)  -    Do you want to make this an official answer so i can approve ?   up to u... but happy to do so...


$$=10\left[\frac{-20}{5}-\frac{1}{(20-\omega)^2} \cdot \frac{d(-\omega)}{d t} \cdot \omega\right]$$

$\frac{d(-w)}{dt}$ is $-\frac{dw}{dt}$, not simply $-1$.

once bitten twice shy ... never again will i repeat that stupid mistake !   thnx again ;^)
